# ListView using custom adapter.

Tags: java, android, listview

I am fetching the data form sql database and retrieving it using JSON

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

        ArrayList<String> personList=null;
        for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String roll = c.getString(TAG_ROLL);

            personList = new ArrayList<String>();
            personList.add(i, roll);
     }
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, persons);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Now, When I am passing the data to MyCustomAdapter class, the arraylist needs to change from String to type Student(Which is a class)

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
 public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public ArrayList<Student> personList;
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Student> personList) {
    super(context, resource, personList);
    this.personList=new ArrayList<Student>();
    this.personList.addAll(personList);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView roll;
    TextView name;
    CheckBox check;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.roll=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.roll);
        holder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.check=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) v;
                Student student=(Student)cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                        " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                student.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Student student=personList.get(position);
    holder.roll.setText(" (" +  student.getRollno() + ")");
    holder.name.setText(student.getName());
    holder.check.setChecked(student.isSelected());
    holder.check.setTag(student);

    return convertView;

}
}
```

Student.java

```
  public class Student {
String rollno;
String name;
Boolean selected;

public Student(String rollno, String name, Boolean selected){
    super();
    this.rollno=rollno;
    this.name=name;
    this.selected=selected;
}
public String getRollno(){
    return rollno;
}
public void setRollno(String rollno){
    this.rollno=rollno;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public Boolean isSelected(){
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

How should I be passing data to my custom adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Adapter class you must have a ArrayList list . but you are preparing a String type list from json .. thats the problem..
you can do it like this way

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
    peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

    ArrayList<Student> personList=new ArrayList<Student>();;
    for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {

       Student student = new Student();            
       JSONObject c = new JSONObject(peoples.getString(i));
       student.setName(c.getString("NAME");
       student.setRollNo(c.getString(TAG_ROLL));

       personList.add(student);
     }
```

may be you need to customize this logic based on your json pattern..

and now use this Student list to your adapter

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, personList);
listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was stuck at it for such a long time. +1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u create an arrayList with Student as members....

```
ArrayList<Student> personList= new ArrayList();
```

and I dont understand why u have the following statement inside a for loop i suggest u do it before the loop or else ull end up only one value in ur array list

```
personList = new ArrayList<String>();
            personList.add(i, roll);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to do this. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/) is a json parsing library. A Java serialization/deserialization library that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back.

To use Gson in a Gradle build, add

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

or a later version as dependency to your build.gradle build file

In your student model class, use @SerializedName("key_name") as a annotation for each field then there is no need to create a constructor in you model class

key_name is a key in json object.

```
{
   "key_name":"key_value"
}
```

like I have created.

```
public class Student {
@SerializedName("roll_no")
String rollno;
@SerializedName("name")
String name;
@SerializedName("selected")
Boolean selected;

public String getRollno(){
    return rollno;
}
public void setRollno(String rollno){
    this.rollno=rollno;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public Boolean isSelected(){
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

Also create one more model class (say Result.java) in which you can define a list of Student class as a field to this class.

```
public class Result{

@SerializedName("result")
List<Student> student_list;

public List<Student> getStudent_list() {
    return student_list;
}

public void setStudent_list(List<Student> student_list) {
    this.student_list = student_list;
}
}
```

Now fetch result from sql database and convert result json into Result class object.

```
try { 
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
    Result result_object = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), Result.class);
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, result_object.getStudent_list());
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```